# Plotting a database of locations on a Google Map

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, google-maps

I have 100K+ lat/longs in a SQL database, and I want to plot them on a google map. The user will input an address to find points close to that address. How should I do this? I have the map working, with the ability for the user to enter an address and have the map center on this point. Just need to add the pins.

I'll be building the front end in JS, and any backend needs in PHP.

Comment: This question seems too broad.  At a high level, you need to run some query on your DB to fetch a reasonable number of lat/long pairs near the user-submitted address.  You return those to your page (using an AJAX call, for instance) and then just add some `GMarker`s for each lat/long in the result set.

Comment: Thanks, I will edit to be more specific.

Comment: Seconding what aroth said - not sure which bit you are having trouble with (e.g. SQL structure, SQL query, pumping data to the maps api etc). If you have something you've tried (or thought of) put that in so we know where to concentrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets start with the search for address, I would use the [Google places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search). This will allow you to localise your results and get the coordinates of the place in question.

Once you have the coordinates I would head off to the server to do a lookup, if you are using MySQL you can use their spatial extensions which have some handy ways of indexing things spatially.

You say you have 100k items, obv there is NO way that you can send all of them to the frontend to display on the map, you will need to limit your result set or else the users browers will cry tears of blood as it tries to render and handle all of them. You can have a look at the [Google Maps Marker Clusterer](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/examples.html) for a nice way of displaying a high density of markers.